# Regular expression to match Google Maps URLs

Tags: php, regex

Am new with regular expression
I want to compare string of url which must match a specific Url, if it match it return true false otherwise. e.g My url is [http(s)://map.google.{ any letter here }/maps](http://www.elands.mle-techies.co.ket)

must strickly match the above expression in that format please help

Comment: Are you after C# code, PHP code, or just the regex pattern?

Answer (score 5):

UPDATED (to include requests from comments)

This should work:

```
^(http(s?)://)?maps\.google(\.|/).*/maps/.*$
```

Note this will now allow either a `.` or a `/` after the literal word `google` so both of the following will match:

```
maps.google/co.ke/maps/anything
maps.google.co.ke/maps/anything
```

Here is the same reg ex with comments from RegexBuddy to help you understand it

```
@"
^           # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   http        # Match the characters “http” literally
   (           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
      s           # Match the character “s” literally
         ?           # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )
   ://         # Match the characters “://” literally
)?          # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
maps        # Match the characters “maps” literally
\.          # Match the character “.” literally
google      # Match the characters “google” literally
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
               # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      \.          # Match the character “.” literally
   |           # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      /           # Match the character “/” literally
)
.           # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
/maps/      # Match the characters “/maps/” literally
.           # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$           # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

This is how you would use it in php:

```
$subject = 'maps.google/co.ke/maps/anything';
if (preg_match('%^(http(s?)://)?maps\.google(\.|/).*/maps/.*$%', $subject)) {
    echo 'Successful match';
} else {
    echo 'Match attempt failed';
}
```

And this is how you would use it in C#:

```
var subjectString = "maps.google/co.ke/maps/anything";
try {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"^(http(s?)://)?maps\.google(\.|/).*/maps/.*$")) {
        // Successful match
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Also, have you noticed that your url for google is `map.google` - shouldn't it be `maps.google`? I have assumed so in my answer based on the input you used in your comment below.

Comment: i have tried it ,i implemented it this way<?php

$string="http://maps.google/co.ke/maps";


if (preg_match('%^https?://maps\.google\..*/maps$', $string)) {
    echo" Successful match";
} else {
    echo" Match attempt failed";
}











?> but it keep echoing Match attempt failed. and a warning "Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '%' found in C:\wamp\www\c\s.php on line " one more thing i wanted to match it this way i think i forgot http://maps.google/{anything}/maps/{anythinh}

Comment: @user1058997 it's not working for 2 reasons. 1) you are missing the `%` at the end of your pattern (like the warning says) 2) the `$string` you are trying to match is different from the one you asked for. You asked for there to be a `.` after `google` but you are trying to match it with a `/` after `google`. Which do you want? Also, i'll update the answer so that it allows anything at the end (like you asked for) and makes the `https://` optional (with optional `s` as well).

Comment: @user1058997 excellent, i'm happy to help. Please remember to accept the question if it solved your problem and upvote it if you feel it deserves it. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/181101)